# Java Protocol Buffers - Convert DynamicMessage to Message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Is is possible to convert DynamicMessage to Message in proto bufs? I know Message can be converted into DynamicMessage though.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DynamicMessage` implements the `Message` interface, so it already is a `Message`.  Do you mean you want to convert a `DynamicMessage` to a specific type generated using `protoc`?  In that case, the best thing to do is serialize the message and then parse it again.

```
MyMessageType.parseFrom(dynamicMessage.toByteString());
```